# TwythonError: Twitter API returned a 404 for string 'usernames'

Tags: python, twitter, twython

I am refering to this [article](http://social-metrics.org/twitter-user-data/).The article used `twython` to download user profile information with reference to `UserID` (int) and I am trying to use `username`(str).

The exact same code works when `userID` is given and when the same user's `username` is given this gives me an error.

what should I change in the program to read and process the usernames ? I have checked several question here and other forums the `404` is shown when the user is no longer available twitter user.

But to test that theory I did use same userid and username of which I can return the user profile fields but when the same user's username or screenname is used I am getting error.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "user_prof_twython.py", line 25, in <module>
    users = t.lookup_user(user_id = ids)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twython/endpoints.py", line 522, in lookup_user
    return self.get('users/lookup', params=params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twython/api.py", line 264, in get
    return self.request(endpoint, params=params, version=version)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twython/api.py", line 258, in request
    api_call=url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twython/api.py", line 194, in _request
    retry_after=response.headers.get('X-Rate-Limit-Reset'))
twython.exceptions.TwythonError: Twitter API returned a 404 (Not Found), No user matches for specified terms.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me. Is this what you want?

Please note, screen_name can be a list. e.g.: ["aaaa","bbb","ccc","ddd"]

```
# Create a Twython instance with your application key and access token
twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, oauth_version=1)

output = twitter.lookup_user(screen_name="BarackObama")

for user in output:
    print user["id_str"]
    print user['created_at']
    print user['followers_count']
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. May I please request to for uername to be read from the csv and write to csv in the same columns format. Input https://www.dropbox.com/s/pd76cafkwd9uib4/user_keyword.csv?dl=0

Comment: This may help you http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/systems-programming/using-the-csv-module-in-python/